# What are the ways to parse a string to a quickfixgo message in golang.?

Tags: quickfixgo

I buffer fix messages in Apache Kafka in string topic and later need to send these messages to another fix server to send it to the clients.

I can easily do it in quickfix/n however I need to use quickfix/go and host it on Kubernetes.